# apt-get and login problem

Tags: apt, logging

I had a problem when I try to update my ubuntu "12.04LTS": Accidentally I turn off my computer, while the update was running. When I turn it on and try to complete the update, he always told me, that it´s a problem with the "apt-get". I just decide not to install it and then I couldn´t start my ubuntu any more, I always come in a point at the beginning like a terminal, where I have to give my username, but I forgot it. Any suggestions?! Thanx!.J :)

Answer (score 0):

Boot into recovery mode command line and have a look at the directories under /home

```
cd /home
ls
```

The directory you see there will most likely be your username.  If you've also forgotten the password you can reset it by following the instructions given in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).

To repair the broken upgrade try the following:

- Boot into recovery mode
- Start networking services
- Select Repair broken packages with dpkg